# How to define object variables (javascript like) in Typoscript

Tags: typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I have a list of variables that are something like this:

```
pageName = TEXT
pageName.value = "My Name"
pageDescription = TEXT
pageDescription.value = "My Description"
pageID = TEXT
pageID.value = "uhz2773"
pageImg = Text
pageImg.value = "/myPath/to/image.jpg"
..
```

and I use it like

```
<img src="{pageImg}" />
```

is there a way to put those variables together like:

```
myPage = {
    name: "My Name"
    description:"My Description"
    ID: "uhz2773"
    pageImg: "/myPath/to/image.jpg"
}
```

and use it as:

```
<img src={myPage.img} />
```

I am not sure how to declare this variable in a way that works. Which variable type should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a COA

```
myPage = COA
myPage{
    10 = TEXT
    10.value=my Name
    20 = TEXT
    20.value = My Description
    30 = TEXT
    30.value = uhz2773
    40 = TEXT
    40.value = /myPath/to/image.jpg
}
```

so you should output it as

```
<img src={myPage.40} />
```

Comment: That is close but it is not very clear to read. I would know eventually what `myPage.40` means but to another (new) person that have to edit my code it would be not easy, specially if I have +20 properties.

Comment: The Problem is, that TS in Text works as an array. i chose as object an COA Content object array, where any of the parts of which it consists, can be any content object (TEXT,IMAGE or even COA). So there is no other constellation to do it like you want, but to make an extension in which you  can directly access your typoscript.